Datagrip - doesn't return 'RESULT" after "ERROR MESSAGE"
I've been using SSMS for a couple of years and now I changed my tool to ‘DataGrip'. I've got some internal SQL procedures which return an error inside the procedure and describing the error in the “Messages” card and in the “Result” card- improve the procedure.
When I tried it on DataGrip - I've got and error but I cant see the “Result”. How can I turn it on ?


Thanks !
I've been searching all FAQ and Instructions.

How is the error raised? Can you provide an example of the procedure?
